# How to convert Mat to byte array in android opencv?

Tags: android, opencv, mat

Step 1: I was converted Mat to byte array using below method

```
MatOfByte matOfByte = new MatOfByte();
  Imgcodecs.imencode(".png", mRgba, matOfByte); 
   byteArray = matOfByte.toArray();
```

its efficiently converted byte array values. But when i calculate time taken for this method is 100 - 200ms and above.

Step2: I did one sample in Opencv Facedetection, i pass a byte array value to native i have FPS count is 1.314.

Step3: Before that for my analyse I didn't call native just i return a same capture Mat i have FPS count 13 to 18 frames per second.

Step4: Problem i found is Mat to Byte array conversion it takes more time to convert so i didn't get any improvements in FPS.

Step5: I change conversion method

```
byte[] return_buff = new byte[(int) (mRgba.total() * 
                mRgba.channels())];
mRgba.get(0, 0, return_buff);
```

this method cannot take more time to convert but when i was Pass a byte array to native, channels value changed to 1 and image not found.

Is there any other solution to convert byte array, please justify me, thank you

Comment: Can't you use the the constructor in step 1: ```MatOfByte matOfByte = new MatOfByte(mRgba)``` without encoding it as png?

Comment: @boaz001 Without encoding  it shows illegal arguments exception-Incompatible Mat

Comment: That `imencode` function encodes (compresses) the image and stores it in a memory buffer `matOfByte` which is a time-consuming procedure. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: @kornel i just want to convert Mat to byte[]. Any other conversion method having less time to convert.

Comment: sorry, I wanted to ask why instead of what.

Comment: @kornel Facedetection sample in opencv, i get Frame per second 1.314fps  due to conversion delay. without Conversion 13-18 frames per sec i get. In camera capture image is delay for every frame for processing. Thats why i ask